# XSD: The attribute type is missing

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xsd

I am trying to use XSD on a XSD schema generated by [trang](https://github.com/relaxng/jing-trang). It is giving me the following error:

```
>xsd examcard.xsd /nologo /classes
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 33, position 12.       
[...]
Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'examcard'.                                                                                                                                                                                         
  - The attribute type is missing.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".
```

What does this error means ? How should I include the type `type` for XSD to work ?

For reference `examcard.xsd` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
[...]
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="xsi.xsd"/>
```

where `xsi.xsd` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
[...]
<xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
```

And current version is:

```
>xsd /?
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility                                                                                                                                                                                          
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.8.3928.0]
```

---

Full code at:

- https://github.com/malaterre/ExamCard/blob/master/xsd/examcard.xsd

Comment: XSD 1.1 explicitly says that the XSI namespace is built-in, and should not be imported. I know this was stated because existing XSD 1.0 processors interpreted the spec in different ways. But I don't know much about the Microsoft schema processor.

Comment: Ok then. I did report an issue against `jing-trang` project [here](https://github.com/relaxng/jing-trang/issues/205#issuecomment-1275817067).

Comment: Glad you found the schemas since you last posting.  Error means that you are missing some of the schemas.   The schema you posted have import statements at top to include other schemas. Make sure you have to other schemas.  Also you may have to replace the URL in the schema if you move the location.  The TYPE NMTOKEN is defined in one of the child schemas.  Some schema have user defined types and NMTOKEN could one of these types.

Comment: You may want to read following. https://docu.tips/documents/generation-of-cda-xml-schema-from-dicom-images-using-hl7-standard-2-5c1248eb1053e?force_isolation=true  HL7 is a standard the IEEE developed for Medical Industry to exchange medical records.  DICOM is the standard for Medical Images.

Comment: If your schema doedsn't work try this one : https://web.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10gR2/appdev.102/b14297/ap_xmlschms.htm?force_isolation=true